# show only the table rows that contain <td> and have a checked check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I show only the table rows that contain `<td>` and have a checked check box?

```
var myTable = '#testTable';

$(myTable).find('tr').has('checkbox:checked').has('td').show();
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add a example html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#testTable>tr>td>input[type=checkbox]:checked').closest('tr').show();
```

Comment: Wouldn't parents() have the potential to mess things up if #testTable is nested inside another table though?

Comment: I don't think so because it relative to the table that called it - anyone know?

Comment: I think it's better to replace parents('tr') with closest('tr')

Comment: Hello-World: No it's not relative to anything, it works its way back up the entire DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#testTable tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked').show();

$('#testTable>tr>td>input[type=checkbox]:checked').show(); // if you want to make sure they are the direct descendants (only first descendant level)
```

Comment: thanks - and what about the <td> to ensure its in a rows tat has <td>s

Answer (score 1):

You want to show/hide the **row** not just the cell right?

Need to use `.parent().parent()` to step back up to `tr` element.

```
$('#testTable>tr>td>input[type=checkbox]:checked').parent().parent().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this efficiently depends on the fact that you traverse the node you want to manipulate in the XPath query. This means that making all subsequent XPath query should actually be done as a filtering sub-search. That's pretty trivial to do; putting square brackets around it does the trick (and adding a `.` because of the use of `>`):

```
$('#testTable>tr[.>td>input[type=checkbox]:checked]').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

```
var myTable = '#testTable';
$(myTable).find('tr').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('checkbox:checked').length)
        $(this).show();
});
```